# ctr equivalent of `docker run -it --rm apache/camel-k kamel version`

Tags: docker, kubernetes

**Solution:**

```
sudo ctr run -t --rm apache/camel-k uniqueID kamel version
```

**Original question:**

My goal is to install Camel-K CLI `kamel` on a server. I want to achieve it by calling an image as container and I have made it work use docker command, unfortunately the production server doesn't have `docker` CLI installed but there's `kubectl` and `ctr` installed, I tried converted the docker command to kubectl equivalent command, it works but it is slow to terminate the running pod, therefore I am trying to use `ctr` unfortunately haven't succeed.

```
docker run -it --rm apache/camel-k kamel version
```

- I have a docker image `apache/camel-k`
- start a container run the command and then remove the container

Here's what I have tried with `kubectrl`

```
kubectl run tmp-pod -i --rm --image=apache/camel-k -- kamel version
```

Does anyone know how to convert it to equivalent `ctr` command?

Comment: I have figured out the solution "sudo ctr run -t --rm apache/camel-k uniqueID kamel version" , a uniqueID is required for a container if use ctr.

Comment: Please post this solution as an answer, not in the question.

Answer (score 0):

OP found a solution by themselves, in the comments, hence the CW.

---

A uniqueID is required for a container if use ctr

```text
sudo ctr run -t --rm apache/camel-k uniqueID kamel version
```